# How to Speed Up Typescript Queries to SQL server

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function in c# application:

```
foreach (var p in proglist)
{
  programData.GetData1= new List<GetData1_ViewModel>(GetData1(programid, reportingdate));
  programData.GetData2= new List<GetData2_ViewModel>(GetData2(programid, reportingdate));
  programData.GetData3= new List<GetData3_ViewModel>(GetData3(programid, reportingdate));
  programData.GetData4= new List<GetData4_ViewModel>(GetData4(programid, reportingdate));
  programData.GetData5= new List<GetData5_ViewModel>(GetData5(programid, reportingdate));
}
```

I have the same function in a Typescript application:

```
for (const p of proglist) {
  this.data1 = [];
  this.data2 = [];
  this.data3 = [];
  this.data4 = [];
  this.data5 = [];
  await Promise.all([
    (this.data1 = await this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData1")),
    (this.data2 = await this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData2")),
    (this.data3 = await this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData3")),
    (this.data4 = await this.GetData4(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData4")),
    (this.data5 = await this.GetData5(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData5")),
  ]);
}
```

They both call the same database tables, storedprocedures, etc.

The C# code takes 5 seconds to complete
The Typescript code takes 189 seconds to complete

I don't understand why the C# is so much quicker than Typescript. What should I be looking at to speed this up?

Comment: Well... let's just say TypeScript (JavaScript) isn't the fastest language in the world.

Comment: Hard to say without any context... What's `GetData4` and `GetData5`? What's `GetMeasureForScorecard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.GetMeasureForScorecard()` and `this.GetData5()` return a `Promise` that once resolved will contain the value queried, then you don't need to `await` inside `Promise.all()`, because you'll be defeating it's purpose, which is to resolve unresolved promises (non-awaited).

```js
for (const p of proglist) {
  const [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5] = await Promise.all([
    this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData1"),
    this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData2"),
    this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData3"),
    this.GetData4(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData4"),
    this.GetData5(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData5"),
  ]);
}
```

Making multiple functions call with the `await` keyword will force the JS interpreter to make sequential calls instead of concurrent calls (or quasi-concurrent), which is what you are looking for (I assume).

```js
await this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData1");
// Waits until Promise above is resolved
await this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData2"),
// Waits until Promise above is resolved
await this.GetMeasureForScorecard(p.programId, reportingdate, "GetData3"),
```

Comment: Thanks - I think this is the best I can hope to gain. It went from 189 seconds to 37 seconds.

Comment: @FlyFish You are welcome. 

If you want to go further in optimisations, maybe you could consider limiting the rows you are fetching at once, if possible of course. If the data doesn't change that often, caching it with an in-memory database (Redis / Memcached) might give you a boost.